# Mobile Exception design with different store view

Tags: theme, rwd, design, mobile, theme-fallback

I´m running 1.7.0.2
I have different store views I´m creating right now, and already have the design exception for the mobile version, now I need to create template exception for the mobile in different store views, how to do that without recreating the entire folder, let´s say in iphone_norwegian so it fall back to the iphone folder and not the default as it does right now?
There is an excpetion hyerarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end Magento structure hierarchy does not allow this, so I had to work it out differently, so having to recreate an identical norwegian folder with the iphone_norwegian depending to it, This create the problem that every time I edit the original folder I have to copy all edit on the Norwegian folder as well